# Code for reversing an array in JavaScript fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits = fruits.sort();
document.write(fruits);
for(var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(fruits.length / 2); i++) {
    var temp = fruits[i];
    fruits[i] = fruits[fruits.length - 1 - i];
    fruits[fruits.length - 1 - i] = temp;
}
document.write(fruits);
```

I'm trying to make a reverse of the ordered (a-z) array fruits, in order to make it z-a in the for loop. Why isn't this working?

Comment: We don't vote to close when a solution's been found. That's reserved for off-topic or inappropriate questions, etc.

Comment: With your rep, you should be able to close your own question. But better yet, post your solution, and then in a couple of days mark that as the accepted answer (if Patrick's doesn't do it for you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Just use `.reverse()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
fruits.reverse();
```

Comment: Too easy :D No, but I want to do it like this.

Comment: @DarkLightA then tough cookies.

Comment: Got it. Two errors: firstly I used ceil() instead of Math.ceil(), and I forgot to print the outcome!